# Can i Convert this array to List or Set in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have to convert this array into List or set as I am working with Spring boot where I have mentioned this particular this as a list.

```
this.employee.project=[this.projectByName];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const array = [1,2,3,3];
const set = new Set(array);
```

Javascript doesn't have List in the standard library.